# Animating UIView - Stuck in Recursive Animation Loop: Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uianimation

I am stuck in an animation loop. I have a button named [`stopBtn`] and a UIView named [`backgroundView`]. I want to animate the background color of the UIView from the time the ViewController is loaded to the time it is destroyed. in `viewDidAppear` function, I start the pulsating by writing `animateView()`

```
func animateView(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.stopBtn)
        }, completion: {
            (Completed: Bool) -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
                self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 39, green: 117, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.stopBtn)
                }, completion: {
                    (Completed : Bool) -> Void in

                    self.animateView()
            })
    })
}

@IBAction func stopBtnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print("pressed")
}
```

My Question is that why does my `stopBtn` not work? I already know that it's stuck in the loop thats why I would like help to animate properly (maybe on another thread or something and leave the main thread open).

`stopBtn` is connected to another ViewController in Storyboard. I have tried creating a IBAction and that didn't work. I've also tried to bring `stopBtn` to the front of the subview [`self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.stopBtn)`].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation I found that using animateWithDuration temporarily disables user interaction for the views being animated. If you want to enable user interaction you must set the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction constant in the options parameter.

Comment: This answer was absolutely phenomenal. Thank you were much Tyler!